# Javascript : Store JSON data in array

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON like this.

```
[{
    "address": "A-D-1",
    "batch": [{
        "batch_number": "B-123",
        "cost": [{
            "cost": "C1"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "address": "A-85-1",
    "batch": [{
        "batch_number": "B-6562",
        "cost": [{
            "cost": "C16464"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "address": "A-522-1",
    "batch": [{
        "batch_number": "B-4511",
        "cost": [{
            "cost": "C8745"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I would like to store my JSON data to array.

```js
let data = JSON.parse('[{"address":"A-D-1","batch":[{"batch_number":"B-123","cost":[{"cost":"C1"}]}]},{"address":"A-85-1","batch":[{"batch_number":"B-6562","cost":[{"cost":"C16464"}]}]},{"address":"A-522-1","batch":[{"batch_number":"B-4511","cost":[{"cost":"C8745"}]}]}]');

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

if (data[i].batch !== undefined && data[i].batch !== null && data[i].batch.length !== undefined && data[i].batch.length > 0) {
  let batchLength = data[i].batch.length

  let newObject = {}
  let newArray = []

  for (let j = 0; j < batchLength; j++) {
    if (data[i].batch !== undefined && data[i].batch[j].cost !== null && data[i].batch[j].cost.length !== undefined && data[i].batch[j].cost.length > 0) {
      let costLength = data[i].batch[j].cost.length
      for (let k = 0; k < costLength; k++) {

        newObject.location = data[i].address
        newObject.batch.number = data[i].batch[j].batch_number ? data[i].batch[j].batch_number : ''

        newObject.cogs = data[i].batch[j].cost[k].cost ? data[i].batch[j].cost[k].cost : ''
        newArray.push(newObject)
      }
    }
  }
}

}
```

I have stored JSON in `data` variable.

I have tried below code. but I always get last index as repeatative.

Expected Output :

```
[
   {
      "address":"A-D-1",
      "batch":{
         "batch_number":"B-123"
      },
      "cost":"C1"
   },
   {
      "address":"A-85-1",
      "batch":{
         "batch_number":"B-6562"
      },
      "cost":"C16464"
   },
   {
      "address":"A-522-1",
      "batch":{
         "batch_number":"B-4511"
      },
      "cost":"C8745"
   }
]
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you receive the JSON data as String?

Comment: I get as an array of objects.

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: @tevemadar. I have edited my question. Can you please check ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
const someArray = [{
  "address": "A-D-1",
  "batch": [{
    "batch_number": "B-123",
    "cost": [{
      "cost": "C1"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "address": "A-85-1",
  "batch": [{
    "batch_number": "B-6562",
    "cost": [{
      "cost": "C16464"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "address": "A-522-1",
  "batch": [{
    "batch_number": "B-4511",
    "cost": [{
      "cost": "C8745"
    }]
  }]
}]

console.log(someArray.map(item => {
return {
address:item.address,
batch_number: item.batch && item.batch[0].batch_number,
cost: item.batch && item.batch[0].cost[0].cost
}
}))
```

Comment: yes but I can have multiple arrays inside each array. so how can I solve that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to retrieve the same in array format.

```
const data = JSON.parse(someArray);
console.log (data[0].address);
```